# Refused to frame '' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-src *" Trying to set for tel: explicity here

Tags: visual-studio, iframe, tel

I'm currently trying to build a click to dial link in the browser as an Outlook Addin.  I'm getting the error:

`` Refused to frame '' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-src *". Note that '*' matches only URLs with network schemes ('http', 'https', 'ws', 'wss'), or URLs whose scheme matches `self`'s scheme. tel:' must be added explicitely. [https://localhost:44371/] ``

I've set the meta tags a bunch of different ways trying to explicitly state the tel scheme that they mention.  For instance:

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="frame-src 'self' tel:">`

I've tried about 20 different variations on this.   I've also noticed that many people are saying something about changing the HTTP response headers, but I'm not sure exactly how to do this or even why it would be needed.

I'm working on Visual Studio using a template from their own program.  Because I'm testing this out on my own computer, I've also tried to whitelist my own localhost.  Still nothing.

Here is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="frame-src 'self' tel:">
    <title>standard_item_properties</title>
    <script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="default_entities.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="MicrosoftAjax.js"></script>
    <script src="CallFunctionFile.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- Use the CDN reference to Office.js. -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="default_entities.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- NOTE: The body is empty on purpose. Since this is invoked via a button, there is no UI to render. -->
    <div id="container">
        <div><a id="tel-link">Make Call from Phone</a></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the javascript:

```
// Global variables
let item;
let myEntities;

// The initialize function is required for all add-ins.
Office.initialize = function () {
    const mailbox = Office.context.mailbox;
    // Obtains the current item.
    item = mailbox.item;
    // Reads all instances of supported entities from the subject 
    // and body of the current item.
    myEntities = item.getEntities();
JSON.stringify(myEntities.phoneNumbers[0].originalPhoneString));
 
    // Checks for the DOM to load using the jQuery ready function.
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
        // After the DOM is loaded, app-specific code can run.
    });
    let a = document.getElementById("tel-link");
    a.href = "tel:" + encodeURIComponent(myEntities.phoneNumbers[0].originalPhoneString);
}
```

Comment: May be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60635863/refused-to-frame-because-it-violates-the-following-content-security-policy-di